# Google Maps Heatmap works only when the heatmap data is hardcoded and not when it is generated using a for loop

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to plot a heatmap on Google Maps using the API. On using a hardcoded array of LatLng objects, the rendering works. However, if I then try to remove the hardcoded array and generate the array using a for loop, the rendering fails.

console.log for the 2 array variables give me the same objects.

The js-fiddle is provided here: https://jsfiddle.net/arpanio/7weomu5g/61/

The 2 variables are:

- Hardcoded array: heatmapData
- Generated array: heatmap_data

Please see line 87 and line 88 where I comment out and switch between the 2 variables. The hardcoded option works. The generated array option does not work. I am printing both to console and I don't see any difference in the object (other than actual values of the latitude and longitude).

The js code is reproduced below:

```
var map;
var service;
var infowindow;

function initMap() {
  var sydney = new google.maps.LatLng(45.76404, 4.83565);

  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  map = new google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById('map'), {center: sydney, zoom: 12});
var heatmapData = [
new google.maps.LatLng(45.7523537999999,4.8405),
new google.maps.LatLng(45.7663606,4.8328),
new google.maps.LatLng(45.7603967,4.8557)
];

console.log(heatmapData);

//Data to be obtained from mymap -> KML -> GeoJSON
geo_json = {  
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "name":"merged",
   "crs":{  
      "type":"name",
      "properties":{  
         "name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
      }
   },
   "features":[  
      {  
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{  
            "Name":"Auchan Drive Lyon Saint Priest"
         },
         "geometry":{  
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[  
               4.9252405,
               45.7235401
            ]
         }
      },
      {  
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{  
            "Name":"Auchan Drive Saint Genis (Chapônost)"
         },
         "geometry":{  
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[  
               4.76585360000001,
               45.6992269
            ]
         }
      },
      {  
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{  
            "Name":"Auchan"
         },
         "geometry":{  
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[  
               4.8008698,
               45.7498202
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
};

//Convert GeoJSON to Google-specific heatmap data
var heatmap_data = [];
for(var i = 0; i < geo_json.features.length; i++) {
    var temp = geo_json.features[i].geometry.coordinates;
  heatmap_data.push(new google.maps.LatLng(temp[0], temp[1]));
  //console.log(temp);
  /* var lat_lng = new google.maps.LatLng(temp[0], temp[1]);
  heatmap_data.push(lat_lng); */
}
console.log(heatmap_data);


var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
 /* Problem here */
 data: heatmapData, //This works
 //data: heatmap_data, //This does not
 radius: 50,
  opacity: 0.4
});
heatmap.setMap(map);

  var request = {
    location: sydney,
    radius: '500',
    query: 'Carrefour'
  };

  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

  service.textSearch(request, function(results, status) {
    console.log(results);
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        createMarker(results[i]);
       //console.log(JSON.stringify(results[i].geometry.location));       
      }

      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    }


  });
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    icon: {
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
      scale: 2
    },
    position: place.geometry.location
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change co-ordinates sequence of `temp` variable -

`heatmap_data.push(new google.maps.LatLng(temp[0], temp[1]));`

to

`heatmap_data.push(new google.maps.LatLng(temp[1], temp[0]));`

Working JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/hL7n2fek/

Your `heatmap` is getting generated, but with hardcoded `heatmapData` the co-ordinates are 
`45.7523537999999,4.8405` which points to somewhere in `France` and your google map is initialized nearby to same co-ordinates.

But in your `geometry` property in `geo_json` object, the co-ordinates are specified as [4.9252405, 45.7235401] which points to location
somewhere in `Somalia`. Your google map visible section does not covers this. If you zoom in more, you can see that it is getting generated.

Answer (score 1):

GeoJson specifies the coordinates in the order `[Longitude, Latitude]`.

So, this code:

```
heatmap_data.push(new google.maps.LatLng(temp[0], temp[1])); // temp[0] (is Longitude), temp[1] (is Latitude)
```

should be:

```
heatmap_data.push(new google.maps.LatLng(temp[1], temp[0])); // temp[1] (is Latitude), temp[1] (is Longitude)
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/h1fb5tLr/1/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var service;
var infowindow;

function initMap() {
  var sydney = new google.maps.LatLng(45.76404, 4.83565);

  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: sydney,
      zoom: 12
    });
  var heatmapData = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(45.7523537999999, 4.8405),
    new google.maps.LatLng(45.7663606, 4.8328),
    new google.maps.LatLng(45.7603967, 4.8557)
  ];

  console.log(heatmapData);

  //Data to be obtained from mymap -> KML -> GeoJSON
  geo_json = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "name": "merged",
    "crs": {
      "type": "name",
      "properties": {
        "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
      }
    },
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
          "Name": "Auchan Drive Lyon Saint Priest"
        },
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            4.8405,
            45.7523537999999
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
          "Name": "Auchan Drive Saint Genis (Chapônost)"
        },
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            4.8328,
            45.7663606
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
          "Name": "Auchan"
        },
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            4.8557,
            45.7603967
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  };

  //Convert GeoJSON to Google-specific heatmap data
  var heatmap_data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < geo_json.features.length; i++) {
    var temp = geo_json.features[i].geometry.coordinates;
    // heatmap_data.push(new google.maps.LatLng(temp[0], temp[1]));
    console.log(temp);
    var lat_lng = new google.maps.LatLng(temp[1], temp[0]);
    heatmap_data.push(lat_lng);
  }
  console.log(heatmap_data);


  var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
    /* Problem here */
    // data: heatmapData, //This works
    data: heatmap_data, //This does not
    radius: 50,
    opacity: 0.4
  });
  heatmap.setMap(map);

  var request = {
    location: sydney,
    radius: '500',
    query: 'Carrefour'
  };

  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

  service.textSearch(request, function(results, status) {
    console.log(results);
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        createMarker(results[i]);
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(results[i].geometry.location));       
      }

      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    }


  });
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    icon: {
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
      scale: 2
    },
    position: place.geometry.location
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places,visualization&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```